# HTML & Javascript Equation Input Form [UPDATED]

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

Original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855288/html-javascript-equation-input-form

I now know that asking for things specifically is frowned upon. Now that I see that, I don't know why I ever thought someone would just do my work for me...

Anyways I am relatively new to HTML/Javascript and I would like help to finish this if possible...

I need a way for users to input 2 different variables through an HTML form. Upon submission of the form, the 2 variables will be put into the equation (on the JavaScript side) and there will be an HTML output.

Variables:

```
L = Level
S = Seconds
```

Equation:

```
( 10 ( 3 + ( L * 0.5 ) ) * S ) / 60
```

So far this is what I have come up with...

```
<form>
Level: <input type="text">
<br>
Seconds: <input type="text">
<br>
<input type="submit">
<form>
```

All I know is basic HTML.

I'm not asking for anyone to do my work for me but rather help me. Any information that I could use to further my progress would be very much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML & Javascript Equation Input Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855288/html-javascript-equation-input-form)

Comment: '<form>
    Level: <input type="text" name="level">
    <br>
    Seconds: <input type="text" name="seconds">
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>' @SharonLevy

Answer (score 1):

While HTML5 gives the coder the freedom to use an input outside of the FORM tags, that input is still part of that form and needs to identify the form in the "form" attribute of the input.  To use inputs outside of a form and without being thus identified is semantically incorrect. The OP's choice to use a FORM makes sense. In this particular case, the form can be used without submitting it.  I suggest the following HTML which you may style as you wish:

```
<form>
  <div id="container">
   <label for="L">Level:</label><div><input id="L" type="text"></div>
   <label for="S">Seconds:</label><div><input id="S" type="text"></div>
   <label for="result">Answer: <span   id="result"></span></label>  
  </div>
  <input id="Calculate" type="button"  value="Calculate">
  <input id="reset" type="reset">  
</form>
```

Note since form submission is unnecessary, I omitted the name attribute for all the form elements, and instead access the input values by their id property in the following JavaScript:

```
function getLevelSeconds() {
   var L = f.elements[0].value;          
   var S = f.elements[1].value;
   return { "level" : L,"seconds" : S };
}

function Calc( obj ) {
    var equation = 10 *( 3 + ( obj.level * 0.5 ) );
    equation *= obj.seconds;
    return ( equation /= 60 );
}

function focSelLevel(){
   f.elements[0].select();
   f.elements[0].focus();
}

/** START HERE **/
var d = document;
var f = d.forms[0];
var button = d.getElementById("Calculate");
var result = d.getElementById("result");
var reset  = d.getElementById("reset");

button.onclick = function() {
  var obj = getLevelSeconds();
  result.innerText = Calc( obj );
};

reset.onclick = function() {
   result.innerText = "";
   focSelLevel();
};
window.onload = function() {
  focSelLevel();
};
```

The function *getLevelSeconds()* returns the level and seconds in an object literal which keeps the code neat and avoids creating separate variables for the data.

Note, the improved "reset" function; it resets the input values and clears the answer, too.

This code utilizes closures and event attribute properties to take user input and incorporate it into the indicated equation. After it evaluates,the answer becomes visible, as the text of a result SPAN for the user.

See live **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwdrqE)**

Comment: yeah, i just remembered from old school algebra, that when there is no sign it's implied multiplication

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do it?

Assign IDs to your inputs and you are ready to go!

```
var L = parseFloat(document.getElementById("L").value),
    S = parseFloat(document.getElementById("S").value),
    result = ( 10 * ( 3 + ( L * 0.5 ) ) * S ) / 60;
```

Put that in a function and call that function on form submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything on the client side :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calc() {
    var level = document.getElementById("level");
    var levelValue = parseFloat(level.value);

    var seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
    var secondsValue = parseFloat(seconds.value);

    var answer = (10 * (3 + (levelValue * 0.5)) * secondsValue) / 60;
    document.getElementById("answer").value = answer.toString();
}
</script>

Level: <input type="text" id="level">
<br>
Seconds: <input type="text" id="seconds">
<br>
Answer: <input type="text" id="answer" />
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:calc();">Click</button>
```

Don't forget to include some error-checking code!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the easiest way to explain what you need to do is to actually do it...

First, since you aren't actually submitting form data to your server, just get rid of the `<form>` element. You will also need to name/identify your input elements so we can access them by later in the JavaScript. Since we're not submitting a form, change the submit button to a simple `<button>` element to initiate the calculation. This leaves us with the following HTML:

```
Level: <input id="calc-level" type="text">
<br>
Seconds: <input id="calc-seconds" type="text">
<br>
<button id="do-calculate" type="button">Calculate</button>
<br>
Answer: <input id="calc-answer" type="text">
```

Now we need to write some JavaScript. First, let's define a function that can solve your equation:

```
function solve(level, seconds) {
    return (10 * (3 + (level * 0.5)) * seconds) / 60;
}
```

Note, I would not call this `solve`. I don't know what your output represents, but you should give it a name like `solveForAwesomenessIndex` or something that makes it obvious what your solving for.

The next step is to create a function that will react to the button click. It will parse the input, do the calculation, and output the result:

```
function handleCalculate() {
    var level = parseFloat(document.getElementById('calc-level').value);
    var seconds = parseFloat(document.getElementById('calc-seconds').value);
    var answer = solve(level, seconds);
    document.getElementById('calc-answer').value = answer.toString();
}
```

Finally, we have to hook up a click event to that button. Because I'm a proponent of unobtrusive JavaScript, we aren't going to add any inline event handlers (no intermingled HTML/JavaScript), so we do the event handling programmatically:

```
window.onload = function() { // when the window has loaded
    // Assign the handleCalculate method to the button's click event
    document.getElementById('do-calculate').addEventListener('click', handleCalculate);
};
```

See it in action: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/okpv89nu/)